# When is the Radon-Nikodym derivative locally essentially bounded

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, integration

Let $\mu\lll\nu$ be $\sigma$-finite Borel measures, which are not *finite*, on a topological space $X$.  Under what conditions is $0<\operatorname{ess-supp}(\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}I_K)<\infty$ for every compact subset $\emptyset\subset K\subseteq X$.

In other words when is $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu} \in L^{\infty}_{\nu,\mathrm{loc}}(X)$?

Comment: My google ninja's skill got me the following: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3119941/what-are-sufficient-conditions-for-the-boundedness-of-a-radon-nikodym-derivative is this helpful?

Comment: @Alan It is pretty interesting, but I don't want to assume any such geometric structure.  Btw, I like the ninja skills terminology I'll have to borrow it :)

Comment: I got this terminology from someone else in physicsforums, can't remember from whom though. :-D

Comment: What type of conditions do you need?

Comment: Something digestible to a non-analyst audience.  This has come up as an example basically.

Comment: in fact $\| \frac{d\mu}{d\nu}\|_{\infty,K}=\sup_{H\subset K} \frac{\mu(H)}{\nu(H)}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$f:=\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}.$$ Then 
$$f\in L^{\infty}_{\nu,loc}(X)\iff\text{$\forall$ compact $K\subseteq X$ $\exists$ $c_K\in(0,\infty)$ $\forall$ Borel $A$ we have $\mu(A\cap K)\le c_K\nu(A\cap K)$.}$$

Indeed, for the $\Rightarrow$ implication, take any compact $K\subseteq X$. Then $\exists$ $c_K\in(0,\infty)$ such that $f\le c_K$ $\nu$-a.e. on $K$. So, for any 
Borel $A$ we have 
$$\mu(A\cap K)=\int_{A\cap K}f\,d\nu\le c_K\nu(A\cap K),$$
as desired.

Vice versa, for the $\Leftarrow$ implication, take any compact $K\subseteq X$ and suppose that $\mu(A\cap K)\le c_K\nu(A\cap K)$ for some $c_K\in(0,\infty)$ and all Borel $A$. Let now $A:=f^{-1}((c_K,\infty))$, so that $f>c_K$ on $A$. Then 
$$\mu(A\cap K)=\int_{A\cap K}f\,d\nu\ge c_K\nu(A\cap K),$$
and the latter inequality is strict (and hence contradicts condition $\mu(A\cap K)\le c_K\nu(A\cap K)$) if $\nu(A\cap K)>0$. So, $\nu(A\cap K)=0$, that is, $f\le c_K$ $\nu$-a.e. on $K$, as desired.

---

Similarly, for any compact $K\subseteq X$, 
$$\operatorname{esssup}_Kf>0\iff \text{ $\exists$ $b_K\in(0,\infty)$ $\exists$ Borel $A$ such that $\mu(A\cap K)\ge b_K\nu(A\cap K)$.}$$

Comment: As a general question of interest, is this relation used/ does it have a name or is it a bit arbitrary?

Comment: @AnnieTheKatsu : I don't know of a name for this relation. It should be folklore, rather transparent from a standard proof of the Radon--Nikodym theorem; cf. the comment by Pietro Majer.